# Opening specific file types with a different protocol in SharePoint Online?

Tags: sharepoint-online

Apparently we cannot manage different MIME types when migrating from Sharepoint on premise to Sharepoint Online:

Source: 
 - https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/adding-mime-types-in-sharepoint-online/00028722-2d47-4355-8c6a-5ce6a0e592a1

Is there a way around this like automatically modifying the link for specific file types to use a different protocol?

Ex: If my library has "blah.myfiletype" as a file, can all links in Sharepoint Online with the ".myfiletype" extension be replaced by "ftp://blah.myfiletype" instead of "http://blah.myfiletype" ?

The goal is to handle file types that are not part of the Microsoft Office suite if we implement our own protocol handler on the client machines since Micro$oft can't seem to allow MIME type support in Sharepoint Online.